# how implement search value as url parameter in zend

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework

i have following html

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formsearch">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Keyword</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="<?php echo $this->search?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

When i press submit i wish the url should be

> domain.com/users/index/search/{search_word}. And need pagination also.
>
> domain.com/users/index/page/2/search/{search_word}

How should be it possible

Answer (score 0):

In the form, change `method="post"` to `method="get"`. This will not set the url as you want, however it will put the search into the url as a query: `domain.com/users/?search=my+keyword+here&submit=Search`

Alternatively, have you controller redirect the form once it has been received to this url structure?

```
//controller
if($this->getRequest()->isPost() and $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())
{
  $this->_helper->redirecter->gotoRouteAndExit(array('search' => $form->getData('search')), 'searchRoute');
}
```

This is just an example. What it is doing, is checking if the form has been submitted (via post - no changes needed to your form). If the form is valid then redirect to another url. The first parameter of gotoRouteAndExit is an array of parameters; in this case the parameter name is 'search' and the value is gotten out of the form. You will need to create the route (in this code it is named searchRoute) in your bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set form action to `index/search/`. But I think it can't redirect to `index/search/keywords`

```
$form->setAction('/index/search');
```

Also you can redirect to action since your current directory.

```
$this->_redirect('index/search/keywords/values');
```